# Integrating iATS forms through CiviCRM (Drupal) onto website Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, forms, iats, iatspayments

We have installed the iATS plugin to our CiviCRM (on Drupal) and we would like to create an embedded donation form onto our Wordpress website. We don't want to use the CiviCRM public pages because moving donors away from our website will mean fewer people go through with their donations.

I'd like to know if anyone else has encountered this problem, and if they'd be able to share some insight into how best to move forward?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can embed the Drupal site's form (any form, whether from Civi or Drupal) into your wordpress site using an iframe.

Here's an example of exactly that:
https://patientscanada.ca/donate/

There are three steps to make this work:

1. Create an alternative theme on the Drupal site that is suitable for embedding in an iframe. There's a Drupal theme here: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_iframe_theme that will take you most of the way. I can share what I've used if you want.
2. Use theme_key or similar module to display the appropriate path using that theme.
3. Configure your settings.php to allow the wp site to iframe your drupal pages (by default, Drupal will not allow itself to be used in an iframe, as a security precaution).

Comment: See my comment below about the disadvantages of this approach compared with a full theming option described by Karin.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't want to use CiviCRM public pages because it would visually take people away from your main website.

An option could be to theme your CiviCRM public pages so that this transition is absolutely seamless -> here's an example of a CiviCRM public page we're drafting at the moment (with iATS Payments processor but that's not the point) - this organization's main website (which lives on another server elsewhere) theme-wise looks just like it. We themed the public pages of their separate CiviCRM instance to look like their main website.

[image]

Comment: Hello! This sounds great, are you able to point me in the right direction of how to go about creating this? Thank you!!

Comment: It’s essentially theme-ing work. You’ll want to find someone with solid Drupal theme-ing skills to help you with this: override the CiviCRM tpl (templates) that are used to render the page - and then add javascript and css the form the way you want it to look.

Comment: This approach has a number of advantages over the iframe solution:
1. It is immediately transferable to other public pages that can be exposed by CiviCRM (or Drupal).
2. The iframe solution can behave weirdly on things like thank you and error pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange:-)

There are many CiviCRM installations that send data from their public website to their CiviCRM on another server. That should not be a problem in itself. You could use the Form Processor extension (check https://civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor). And you could use CiviProxy (see https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/) to minimize the security impact.

However, you do need to think a little bit about the architecture you want to set up. I am not sure what you want to achieve, and if the iATS plugin is what you need. I have answered based on your request to have donation form on your Wordpress website that sends data to CiviCRM. You should perhaps expand a little on the exact steps you want to make so other with more knowledge about iATS can help you with those details.

Good luck!